# How can remove first letters from a name in smarty?

Tags: foreach, smarty

This code find my first letter and show it. But how can remove it?
Like: From EDCstreet to street.

```
{foreach from=$elements item=street}
  {if $street|substr:0:1 eq 'm'}
       {$street}
  {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
{foreach from=$elements item=street}
  {if $street|substr:0:1 eq 'm'}
       {$street|substr:1}
  {/if}
{/foreach}
```

to display text without this first letter